# Joining 4 tables in mysql giving me duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql

I want to join below 4 tables (leads, categories, sales_persons, website_assigns) in mysql query :

**Required** : i need lead id and lead record  but its not sure that category , sales person exist for that lead,
If they category and sales person exist then come otherwise no required means null.

There is no relation between leads and sales_person direct, they bind with third table which is website_assign

**MySql Query:**

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name, c.first_name, c.last_name
FROM leads a INNER JOIN sales_persons c
LEFT JOIN categories b ON a.category_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN website_assigns d ON a.id = d.lead_id and c.id = d.sales_person_id
```

This above query giving me repeated record of leads, category and sales person table

**Tables:**

```
leads:
id  |   name | category_id
 1      xyz     12
 2      abc     13
 3      def     14
 4      gty     15
 5      wer     16

categories:
id  |   name
12      grocery
13      cloths
14      books
15      travel
16      furniture


sales_persons:    
id  | first_name | last_name

111     Jack        Soloman
112     Peris       Rock
113     Pull        Cha
114     Tim         shock


website_assigns:
id  | lead_id | sales_person_id
1       1           112
2       1           114
3       2           113
4       2           111
5       3           113
6       3           112
7       3           114
```

**Duplicate record screen shot attached:**

See repeated id (Lead id) , name (category name), first name and last  name of sales_person coming,

But 4847, 5868 has only sales person assigned.

In screen shot leadsite_assign is same table website_assign.
So ignore the name of table.

[image]

Comment: . . You query returns exactly what it specifies.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you mean by "duplicate values".

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: So you need your records to be unique?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i attached my duplicate record screen shot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT  
distinct a.id, a.name, b.name, c.first_name, c.last_name 
FROM  leads a 
LEFT JOIN  
website_assigns d on a.id = d.lead_id 
LEFT JOIN 
sales_persons c on c.id = d.sales_person_id 
LEFT JOIN 
categories b ON a.category_id = b.id
```

output :

```
id          name   name    first_name   last_name
---         ----  -------  ---------    --------
1           xyz   grocery     Peris      Rock
1           xyz   grocery     Tim        shock
2           abc   cloths      Jack       Soloman
2           abc   cloths      Pull       Cha
3           def   books       Peris      Rock
3           def   books       Pull       Cha
3           def   books       Tim        shock
4           gty   travel      NULL       NULL
5           wer   furniture   NULL       NULL
```

Understanding Join :

We can see that `leads` and `sales_person` are connected indirectly through `website_assigns` table. Hence we have used LEFT JOIN to join these 3 tables together.

LEFT JOIN basically returns every row from the left side table. Non matching rows from right side table are mapped to `NULL`.

Relation between `categories` and `leads` is straight forward as `a.category_id = b.id`

Comment: perfect. can you please explain its understanding, and flow ?

Comment: @HopeFull : check updated answer. Also read : http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/joining-in-sql.php